# getting wrong answer while changing log value to integer in c++

Tags: c++, function, logging, floor

My task is to calculate `log(a*(x^x))+1` to the base `b` and take its integer part.

```
int temp = log(a)/log(b) + (x*log(x))/log(b) +1 ; // this gave me 25 for a= 2, b= 2, x=8
```

When I changed it to:

```
floor(log(a)/log(b) + (x*log(x))/log(b))+1
```

It worked fine.

What is the difference between both expressions?

Comment: Before the change, you were not "taking the integer part". Which is exactly what `floor` is doing

Comment: `floor()` rounds down.   Floating point operations round toward the nearest value.   Depending on values of `a`, `b`, or `x` you may encounter one or more cases of rounding up - which will give different results than `floor()`.

Comment: Truncating x+1 does not necessarily produce the same value as flooring x, adding 1, and then truncating.

Comment: Probably luck. Note that log returns a double and log(8)/log(2) will not necessarily be exactly 3 but very close and could be slightly lower or higher.